# AngularJS Hebrew Date Converter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I'm making a simple Hebrew Date Converter with AngularJS using the Hebcal Hebrew Date API.

HTML as follows:

```
<body ng-app="HebrewDate">

    <div class="page-container" ng-controller="DateCtrl">

        <input type="text" ng-model="inputYear" placeholder="Year (YYYY)"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="inputMonth" placeholder="Month (MM)"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="inputDay" placeholder="Day (DD)"/>

        <button class="bt bt-achieve" ng-click="url(inputYear, inputMonth, inputDay)">Convert</button>

    </div>

</body>
```

And the script:

```
var app = angular.module('HebrewDate', []);

app.controller('DateCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.url = function(inputYear, inputMonth, inputDay, outputYear) {

        var dateUrl = "http://www.hebcal.com/converter/?cfg=json&gy=" + inputYear + "&gm=" + inputMonth + "&gd=" + inputDay + "&g2h=1";
        var output;

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: dateUrl
        }).success(function(data, status){

            output = angular.fromJson(data);

            outputYear = output.hy;


        }).error(function(data, status){

            // in case of error, sob. 

        }); 

    }

});
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get converted date (e.g. outputYear) to return the the HTML -- trying to get it to display just below the input fields.  I've tried using a div with ng-bind, but I'm obviously missing something. New to AngularJS and would really appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add this to your html:

```
{{outputYear}}
```

---

2) remove outputYear as an argument for your controller function

3) change

```
'outputYear = output.hy;'
```

to

```
'$scope.outputYear = output.hy;'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variable privately inside the controller and the template has no access to it. The template has access to `$scope`, so if you do `$scope.someVar = someValue` then you can use (display) `someVar` inside your template.

As HankScorpio said, you need the modifications as following.

In the controller:

```
$scope.outputYear = output.hy;
```

In your view you can use ng-bind as you mentioned or also:

```
<span>{{outputYear}}</span>
```